# 2D Array in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

It is possible to create 2D Array. I used `m.value = CreateObject("roArray", 0 , true)` But It's only create a one dimensional array. Here I create only single Row and multiple Column
0
1
2
3
I tried to create a 2D array in Roku. Here I tried to create a multiple Row and column-like below.

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3

0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3

1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **'dim'** to create multi-dimensional array.This is easy way. Create like this--

```
dim tempArray[2, 3]      
m.arr = tempArray
```